# What is this medieval city-building game?

Tags: game-identification

Screenshots and videos of this game have been bootlegged in many ads for various different cheap mobile phone games (that have nothing to do with the game shown in the pictures), and the game shown in the pictures is obviously for PCs or Macs since it uses a mouse.  The PC game shown in the pictures actually looks rather fun, kind of like a better looking version of Banished...
Does anyone know what the name of it is?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Google image search reveals nothing- in fact these images don't seem to exist anywhere aside from this post.

Comment: Where'd you find these pictures?

Comment: I'm not sure it is a game... it doesn't look at all familiar and I'm fairly sure a lot of mobile games just use mocked up segments like this in ads to make their games look better.

Comment: The interface just seems a bit off to me. The resource bar doesn´t seem to fit with the rest.

Comment: @Frank the pictures are from various Facebook ads (videos, but I was only able to grab screenshots) for various mobile phone games, such a King of Avalon Dragon Warfare and Guns of Glory.  But it's just a bait-and-switch because the games linked in the ad are just typical 2D isometric tap-and-wait mobile phone games.

Comment: @user224384 The "tappable" nature of the icons above the buildings also suggest that it is (probably false) advertising for a mobile game.

Comment: The final image is definitely using pre-rendered / isometric perspective (it looks a bit like Age of Empires 2?) whereas the others are fully 3D rendered versions of roughly the same scene. That makes me think it's fake, or at least a mix of two different games.

Answer (score 5):

I think this question has been answered exhaustively throughout the comments: **it is footage of fake gameplay of a non-existing game, used as ads to lure in people to play run-of-the-mill casual games.**

Reasoning:

- No additional or duplicate images can be found through reverse image search, none through regular searching;
- the UI seems inconsistent;
- there is a discrepancy between the linear perspective of the first images, and the isometric projection of the last (a feature which, is non-existent, AFAIK, or, at least, rare);
- in the first screenshot, the pathfinding (I assume that's what it is) seems to be wrong, leading me to believe it was cursorily added in post-production (or the pathfinding algorithm is just not optimal).

Also, as suggested in the other answer, it is quite obviously not Forge of Empires, because the two look completely different (even when considering the footage would come from pre-rendered trailers). As far as I could find similar games, it mostly resembles [Foundation](https://www.polymorph.games), but the architectural style and world scale are the most prominent differences.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that it is Forge of Empires, a free browser game.

Comment: https://us.forgeofempires.com/ <- does seem to have very similar concept art

Comment: Close, but Forge of Empires only has a single fixed isometric view.  The game in the screenshots shows a free moving camera since you can see the buildings from many different angles.

Comment: @user224384 are you 100% they're screenies of in-game? Rather than concept art

Comment: The original ads actually showed videos.  But I was only able to grab screenshots.  If the videos were concept art then they were really good.

Comment: @user224384 you'll find that a lot with games like this, videos that look completely different from the actual game - aside from design themes. I think you're looking for something that won't look like the video

Comment: Where are you guys seeing this?  Neither [the actual game](https://us0.forgeofempires.com/page/media/screenshots/) nor the [concept art](https://us0.forgeofempires.com/page/media/testmediagroup/testmediagallery/) looks anything like OP's pictures.

Comment: Agree with @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - I checked out FoE and it's nothing like the above screenshots. It's most likely online though, because of the "Player 1" name in the upper left.